# Object argument in prehandle method of spring Interceptor.. what does it hold?

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

The spring interceptor method prehandle has signature...

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler);
```

**what does the Object handler hold?** I have read somewhere, it is sort of deprecated... Is it safe to use it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it isn't deprecated and yes it is safe to use. It contains the Handler which is about to handle the incoming request. In general this is a `Controller` instance or when using annotations a `HandlerMethod` instance.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) and [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) for additional information.